# Disambiguation between two similar documentaries "World War 2 In Colour"

Tags: alternate-version, ww2-in-hd-colour

There was a popular series on World War 2 that was done in color. [Wikipedia's Entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_War_II_In_HD_Colour) says the following:

> World War II In HD Colour is a 13-episode television documentary series recounting the major events of World War II narrated by Robert Powell.
>
> The show covers the Western Front, Eastern Front, North African Campaign, and the Pacific War. It was on syndication in America on the Military Channel (now American Heroes Channel).
>
> The series is in full colour, combining both original and colourised footage. It was made by World Media Rights in 2008/2009.

Now, I was interesting in watching the full show as I had managed to watch one of the middle episodes on television. I searched on Google and was surprised to find that there was a [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U4gLURNf_h4) with the full documentary.

However, I noticed something surprising. These are not the same documentaries at all and I'm having a little difficulty understanding what the situation is.

I'm asking for disambiguation, what are these 2 documentaries? Are they the same thing only slightly different versions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the end of the video you linked there is a credit for **Series Producer- [Stewart Binns](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0083093/)** and based on his IMDb profile, I believe that YouTube video is actually  **[WWII: The Lost Color Archives (2000)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0275779/)** which he was [credited as **Series Producer**](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0275779/fullcredits) on, along with [Martin Smith](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0809252/) and [Alastair Waddington](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm1507380/?ref_=ttfc_fc_cr11) as executive producers and Editing by [Stephen Moore](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm1162624/?ref_=ttfc_fc_cr13):

[image: Series producer credit]

There are also credits for [Lucy Carter](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0141784/) and [Alastair Laurence](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0491087/) as producers on both the video and IMDb:

[image: Producers]

Using the [name search tool](http://www.imdb.com/search/title?roles=nm1507380,nm0083093,nm0491087,nm1162624,nm0141784,nm0809252) shows this is the only show that combination of people worked on.